# Keycloak and invalidation mode for ISPN cache

Tags: keycloak

I'd like to configure Keycloak with embedded ISPN cache in invalidation mode for user sessions.

According to the doc, invalidation mode means each node gets its own cache and only invalidation is propagated to other nodes (the cache is only useful for read operations). I am aware that performances are non optimal but the JDBC store became a single source of truth which looks interesting to me. Moreover, as I need to store 1 million user sessions a week, the ISPN cache is filled very quickly (6GB instances) and sessions would probably be writen/read from database at a high frequency rate using the passivation/activation mechanism.

http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#replicated_mode

But I can't manage to get it work, no error, but the behavior is not the expected one: the database is still empty after several login operations.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:6.0">
    <cache-container name="keycloak" module="org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
        <local-cache name="realms">
            <object-memory size="10000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="users">
            <object-memory size="10000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <invalidation-cache name="sessions" statistics-enabled="true">
            <binary-memory eviction-type="COUNT" size="1000"/>
            <expiration lifespan="180000"/>
            <jdbc-store data-source="InfinispanDS"
                        dialect="POSTGRES"
                        fetch-state="false"
                        passivation="false"
                        preload="false"
                        purge="false"
                        shared="true"
                        singleton="false">
                <table prefix="ISPN">
                    <id-column name="ID_COLUMN" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                    <data-column name="DATA_COLUMN" type="BYTEA"/>
                    <timestamp-column name="TIMESTAMP_COLUMN" type="BIGINT"/>
                </table>
            </jdbc-store>
        </invalidation-cache>
    </cache-container>  
</subsystem>
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/InfinispanDS" pool-name="InfinispanDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" spy="true">
    <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/keycloak_ispn</xa-datasource-property>
    <security>
        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
        <password>***</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <use-fast-fail>true</use-fast-fail>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <background-validation-millis>60000</background-validation-millis>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
</xa-datasource>
```

Could someone confirm to me that this is supposed to work?

(The other option would be to use a distributed cache with eviction-type="COUNT" and size="1" which actually works, but not more cache at all I guess).

Thanks

**UPDATE 15:09**

Actually, there are traces:

```
15:01:07,748 DEBUG [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanAuthenticationSessionProviderFactory] (default task-1) [node11] Registered cluster listeners
15:01:12,147 DEBUG [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanUserSessionProvider] (default task-1) getUserSessionWithPredicate(2cd1a484-1ba6-4f69-8aec-e85f56029bef): found in local cache
15:01:12,149 DEBUG [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanCodeToTokenStoreProviderFactory] (default task-1) Not having remote stores. Using normal cache 'actionTokens' for single-use cache of code
15:01:12,220 DEBUG [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.changes.InfinispanChangelogBasedTransaction] (default task-1) Replace failed for entity: bd8fe447-b350-45a7-b785-4a4a0c40cb83, old version 9f465b0f-a2ac-407c-a9a1-5f97dca0e337, new version f8b2cf82-c84b-4e57-a058-5e44dba58324. Will try again
```

--nick